# How to calculate pace with minute / km

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im developing an app that needs to calculate the avg pace according to the speed of the distance traveled.

I have this method that returns the distance while I'm walking

```
 private float calculateDistance(LinkedList<LatLng> points) {

        float totalDistance = 0f;
        for (int i =0; i < points.size() -1; i++ ){
            LatLng pointA =  points.get(i);
            LatLng pointB = points.get(i + 1);
            float[] results = new float[3];
            Location.distanceBetween (pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
            totalDistance +=  results[0];
        }

       return totalDistance;

    }
```

Now, I have the time traveled for that distance, so calculating speed would be like `s = distance  / time`  but now I have a concern.

How can I calculate the pace speed in order to be changing depending on the avg speed of the current trayectory.

What I mean is this, If I start an acticity lets say for walking, how can I get the information that Im making a kilometer every 10 minutes while Im walking

I saw runkeeper and they calculate it while you are walking, so if you walk a couple of blocks it will tell you that your pace is like 10 minutes/km

How can I accomplish something like this ? or what is the formula to calculate it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just the inverse.  Time/distance.

Comment: but I need to start the distance at 1 meter at least because if I start from 0 it will throw an infinite number, thats right ?

Answer (score 0):

you just 1/(Minute/Km)=Km/Minute